# Branch cut integral calculation by the method of residues.

Tags: integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

An exercise I'm doing asks me to verify the following identity:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^a}{\left(x+i\right)^2\left(x-i\right)^2}dx=\frac{\left(1-a\right)\pi}{4\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)},\quad -1<a<3.
$$
I've calculated the value of the integral on the left side to be $$
I=\frac{2\pi i\sum\underset{z\to \pm i}{\text{Res}}\left[\dfrac{x^a}{\left(x+i\right)^2\left(x-i\right)^2}\right]}{1-e^{2a\pi I}},
$$
but I can't evaluate the residues in order to prove that the two sides match and solve the exercise. Here it is what I've tried.

*Residues*: these are precisely

$$2\pi i\lim _{z\rightarrow -i}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^ae^{2\pi ia}}{\left(z-i\right)^2}\right)\quad\text{ 
and }\quad2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow i}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^a}{\left(z+i\right)^2}\right)$$
Then the upper side of the fraction above evaluates as
$$
\begin{split}2\pi i\sum \text{Res}\left(f\left(z\right){,}\pm i\right) &=2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{4}i^{a-1}\left(1-a\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{4}\left(-i\right)^{a-1}\left(1-a\right)e^{2\pi ia}\right)\right)\\
& =\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-a\right)\right)\left(e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2}}-e^{\frac{3i\pi a}{2}}\right)\\
&\implies I=\frac{\pi \left(1-a\right)}{4}\cdot 2\cdot \frac{\left(e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2}}-e^{\frac{3i\pi a}{2}}\right)}{1-e^{2i\pi a}}
\end{split}$$

Hence
$$2\cdot\frac{\left(e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2}}-e^{\frac{3i\pi a}{2}}\right)}{1-e^{2i\pi a}}\Rightarrow\ \frac{1}{\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{2}\right)}=\frac{2}{e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2}}+e^{-\frac{i\pi a}{2}}}$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. It looks like you've correctly deduced you should use a keyhole contour. Could you edit in your calculations of the residues? Until you do, I can only guess what went wrong. To compute $\lim_{z\to\pm i}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z^a}{(z\pm i)^2}$, the phases needed are $i^a=e^{ia\pi/2},\,(-i)^a=e^{3ia\pi/2}$. (If you take $y=x^2$ before you use a contour, you only need to work at one pole viz. $(-1)^a=e^{ia\pi}$.)

Comment: Thanks for your edit. It looks like your mistake is in thinking the keyhole's rotation through $2i\pi$ radians changes $z^a$ to $(z+2i\pi)^a$. It actually changes it to $(ze^{2i\pi})^a$, hence your $\frac{1}{1-e^{a2\pi i}}$ factor in $I$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still stuggle to get the correct answer with these corrections.

Comment: When $a = 0,1,2$, your problem is a lot simpler to solve because the integrand doesn't involve a branch cut. If $a$ is any other value in the interval $(-1,3)$, you can use [this keyhole contour](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ohld6dftae). In that Desmos graph, I let $\delta < r< R$ and parameterized the contours into their real and imaginary parts. I gave those parameterizations certain intervals such that they form a closed chain of contours, allowing the use of Cauchy's Residue Theorem like what you did above.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a lot more work to this problem than just calculating the residues since the circular contours take some work to prove they decay to $0$ as $r \to 0^+$ and $R \to \infty$. Also, taking $\delta \to 0^+$ means there will be a phase jump of $2\pi i$ radians when you integrate over the two line segments.

Comment: Wait... On second thought, you can use [this Desmos link instead](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y4oc9vfr6k). I changed the parameterizations to where it's a little easier to integrate over each contour.

Answer (score 2):

First, you seem to have made a sign mistake. A correct computation gives

$$ I = \frac{(1-a)\pi}{4} \cdot \bbox[color:blue; padding:5px; background:#F5E5FF;]{2} \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2}}-e^{\frac{3i\pi a}{2}}}{1-e^{2i\pi a}}. $$

Then we can proceed as follows: Substituting $\omega = e^{i\pi a/2}$ for simplicity,

\begin{align*}
2 \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{i\pi a}{2}}-e^{\frac{3i\pi a}{2}}}{1-e^{2i\pi a}}
&= 2 \cdot \frac{\omega - \omega^3}{1 - \omega^4}
= \frac{2\omega(\omega^2 - 1)}{(\omega^2 - 1)(\omega^2 + 1)} \\
&= \frac{2}{\omega + \omega^{-1}}
= \frac{1}{\cos(\pi a/2)}.
\end{align*}

Plugging this back completes the proof of the identity.